# node while looping asyn function

Tags: node.js

I need to do a sequence of database calls but I don't know exactly how many time.
Something like this

```
DBcall(params, function(err, result) {
  // doing something with result
  if (//condition)
    return;
  // modify params
  DBcall(params, function(err, result) {
    ........
```

I would like to do this in a while loop, like

```
while(//condition) {
  DBcall(params, function(err, result) { 
    ........
  }
  //modify params
}
```

but DBcall return instantly, so it is looping forever, anyway to solve this?

Comment: Take a look at [async.whilst](https://github.com/caolan/async/#whilst) from the async library.

Comment: thx, I thought it didnt work until I realized the callback is mandatory.